# How to get no.of rows different each time and also the values at every execution in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to execute the code below and it doesn't working. I want different rows as output and value also.

```
name_list = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'black']

rr = [random.randint(1,100) for i in list1]
hh = zip(random.choice(list1), rr)
for i in range(random.randint(1,15)):
    for x,v in hh:
            print('"Book Color":',x,',', '"Price: "',v)
```

Every time I run code, I want it will change the no.of rows in output and also change price in each row.

On 1st run:

```
"Book color" : blue, "Price":45
"Book color" : red, "Price":65
```

On 2nd run:

```
"Book color" : black, "Price":5
"Book color" : red, "Price":50
"Book color" : orange, "Price":75
"Book color" : blue, "Price":12
```

On 3rd run:

```
"Book color" : orange, "Price":2
```

Comment: What's the output of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pick a random color and price at every iteration of the `for` loop:

```
import random

name_list = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'black']
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] # change these values to actual prices

for i in range(random.randint(1,15)):
    randomprice = random.choice(list1)
    randomcolor = random.choice(name_list)
    print('"Book Color":',randomcolor,',', '"Price: "',randomprice)
```

First run:

```
"Book Color": black , "Price: " 3
"Book Color": black , "Price: " 3
"Book Color": blue , "Price: " 1
"Book Color": orange , "Price: " 6
"Book Color": black , "Price: " 3
"Book Color": red , "Price: " 6
```

Second run:

```
"Book Color": blue , "Price: " 6
"Book Color": orange , "Price: " 1
"Book Color": blue , "Price: " 5
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider marking my answer as accepted (check mark on the left) since it worked for you.